# Advice on an F# function

Tags: f#, parallel-processing, functional-programming, task-parallel-library

I am currently learning F# and need some advice on this function...  I am testing the Parallel.Invoke.  the  final line is throwing an unexpected indentifier error.    Many thanks.

```
let pmap_tpl_parin f (xs:Array<_>) =
let new_xs = Array.zeroCreate xs.Length
let j = xs.Length - 1
for k in 0..4 do
    Parallel.Invoke (new Action(fun () -> (  for i in  j do   (fun i -> new_xs.[i] <- f (xs.[i]) ))) 
new_xs
```

Comment: BTW, calling `Parallel.Invoke` P.Invoke is quite confusing, because P/Invoke is something completely different.

Comment: Why are you using Actions in F#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee821135.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a closing `)` on the penultimate line. It looks like you want:

```
let pmap_tpl_parin f (xs: _ array) =
    let new_xs = Array.zeroCreate xs.Length
    let j = xs.Length - 1
    for k in 0..4 do
        Parallel.Invoke (new System.Action(fun () -> (for i in j do (fun i -> new_xs.[i] <- f (xs.[i]) ))))
    new_xs
```